# node js socket instance change settimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, chat, bind

i'm trying to write a funny chatbot in node.js & socket.io. there is a deley of 5 second in bot reply. this is working good but when more then one user start chat with a bot there socket instances override to last one. take a look into the code

```
exports.newMessage = function(data, ack){
    var socket = this
    console.log(`newMessage listening`,data);
    botReply = looking4bot(data.message)

        setTimeout( ()=> {
            // if socket reconnected then find correct client
            if(client = users[data.to_user] )
            client.emit("newMessage", botReply)
        }, 5000)
}
```

i carefully read http://javascript.info/bind but did't help. i think bind is not useful here because whenever second user start chat before first's timeout, function rebind and intances override. anyone help me pls to slove issue

Comment: if (a = b) .... Mate, use == or === when you want to test equality!
And a = this is considered as a very bad practice for a few years

Comment: if(client = users[data.to_user] ) i'm using assignment not equity also remove it and use  socket.emit("newMessage", botReply) but same issue @ThéophilePace